# WP Yoast - wp_yoast_indexable - Timeout

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I have an Error in my Dashboard:

> DeleteDuplicateIndexables - Error executing 'query' with: DELETE wyi FROM wp_yoast_indexable wyi INNER JOIN wp_yoast_indexable wyi2 WHERE wyi2.object_id = wyi.object_id AND wyi2.object_type = wyi.object_type AND wyi2.id < wyi.id; Reason: MySQL server has gone away

I figured out, queries with the table wp_yoast_indexable often caus timeout error and 524 Error with cloudflare.

My wp_yoast_indexable has 521.990 data and is 146,2 MiB in size.

I tried to use this instead, but "MYSQL server has gone away." too:

```
delete from wp_yoast_indexable where exists ( select 1 from wp_yoast_indexable wyi2 where wyi2.object_id = wp_yoast_indexable.object_id and wyi2.object_type = wp_yoast_indexable.object_type and wyi2.id < wp_yoast_indexable.id);
```

Any suggestions how to fix this? I have this problem since Version 14 of WP Yoast plugin.

Comment: Have you tried contacting Yoast support on their plugin page on wordpress.org? This is a very specific question about that plugin so you might not get the expertise you need here. They would be in the best position to help.

Comment: I downloaded yoast helper plug in and reset indexables and migrations. Fixed the issue